# What is the fastest way to update a huge amount of data through .Net C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on an application which gets data from two different databases (i.e Database1.Table1 and Database2.Table2) then it compares these two tables ( comparision done only with the primary key i-e ID ) and insert rows from Database1.Table1 to Database2.Table2 if it does not exists in Database2.Table2

The problem is that there is a huge amount of data (about 0.8 Million in both tables ) and it takes a lot of time in comparision. Is there any way to do this Fast

**NOTE: I am using Datatable in C# to compare there tables Code is given below**

```
DataTable Database1_Table1;// =  method to get all data from Database1.Table1
DataTable Database2_Table2;// =  method to get all data from Database2.Table2

foreach (DataRow row in Database1_Table1.Rows) //(var GoodClass in Staging_distinct2)
            {
                if (Database2_Table2.Select("ID=" + row["ID"]).Count() < 1)
                {
                    sqlComm = new SqlCommand("Delete from Database1.Table1 where Id=" + row["ID"], conn);
                    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlComm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Database2.Table2 Values (@ID,@EmpName,@Email,@UserName)", conn);
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row["ID"];
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@EmpName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row["EmpName"];
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row["Email"];
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row["UserName"];
                    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    totalCount++;
                    added++;
                }
                else
                {
                    deleted++;
                    totalCount++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just a note, i wouldn't delete the old till you knew the insert completed. If the insert fails for whatever reason, you've lost data.

Comment: This is only a Demo Code. and my problem is only the data comparison time

Comment: If you have access to the database and if it is SQL Server, then you can go for stored procedure where the operation overhead will handled by SQL Server.

Comment: I don't have any access to Database

Comment: Are the databases on the same server? You can run one query which compares and inserts data _on the server_ without needing to drag data back to your application.

Comment: Yes they are on same server but i need application to do this task.

Comment: If you want to do it in application level, then one optimization i could see is that  you can use ExecuteReader for the first table.

Comment: Your application is doing it. Your application calls a SQL Query. Why would you require the application to do row by row if it's is thousands of times slower that calling a single SQL statement?

Comment: Its not necessary to do this row by row if there is any other solution you can suggest me. I also have use SQL Joins from my application to get data I was thinking that duplication will be removed, But duplication remains in resultant data. [Joins in SQL](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 2):

Submit this SQL from your application to the database:

```
   INSERT INTO Database1..Table1 (Key, Column1,Column2)
   SELECT Key, Column1,Column2 
   FROM Database2..Table2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM Database1..Table1 
      WHERE Database1..Table1.Key = Database1..Table2.Key
   )
```

It will copy all rows that don't match on column `Key` from Database..Table2 to Database..Table1

It will do it on the database server. No needless round trip of data. No RBAR (Row By Agonising Row). The only downside is you can't get a progress bar - do it asynchronously.

Comment: Glad to help. Make sure you test it by running it more than once and ensure that it is only loading in new rows. Also if this helped you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk update/insert is the fastest way. (sqlbulk copy)

http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/

Comment: Yes its a good way to update with bulk but the problem is comparing these dataTables. The loop Takes about 3+ hours. Is there any method to compare these two dataTables in SqlBulk ???

Comment: Not sure but what I think you can avoid loop and filter data on the data set as per your need

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle this is to bulk insert into a temp table then issue a merge statement from that temp table into your production table. I do this with millions of rows a day without issue. I have an example of the technique on my blog [C# Sql Server Bulk Upsert](http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/)